# Categorizing Numeric Values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, rounding

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Y      HePrecip
0      0
0.14   0.19
0.53   0.62
0.86   0.90
```

I want to categorize the `HePrecip` column by grouping values into quarter intervals (e.g., [0, .25], [.26, .50], [.51, .75], [.75, 1.0], ...)

I wrote the following lambda function and helper method to try an accomplish this

```
def my_round(x):
  return math.ceil(x * 4) / 4

df['Categories'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_round(x['HePrecip']), axis=1)
```

The goal is to have .19 round to .25, .62 round to .75, .76 round to 1.0, for example.

However, I get a `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Is this okay?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Comment: `pd.cut(df['HePrecip'], bins=np.arange(20)*0.25)`?

Comment: the warning is unrelated to your code, and more to do with how `df` is created. Perhaps you created it by filtering something larger.